# Detect changes when saving Laravel 4: Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using the Laravel 4 framework and I am trying to work out a way to display notifications depending on whether a `save()` was successful or not. Here's what I have so far:

```
    if($user->save()) {
        Session::flash('success','woohoo success');
    } else {
        Session::flash('error','uhoh error');
    }
    return Redirect::action('UsersController@show', array('users' => $id));
```

My problem is that it always returns true when a user is saved, even if no changes have been made to the database (I know this from the updated_at timestamp). Is there a way to detect whether any changes have actually been made or not using Laravel?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you have some options here. Check out the below first.

**Model Hooks with Ardent package** 
If you are interested in autovalidating models, take a look at the https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent package - Self-validating smart models for Laravel Framework 4's Eloquent O/RM. Apart form great validation features it offers additional model hooks you can use:

```
Here's the complete list of available hooks:

before/afterCreate()
before/afterSave()
before/afterUpdate()
before/afterDelete()
before/afterValidate() - when returning false will halt validation, thus making save() operations fail as well since the validation was a failure.
```

**Laravel Model Events** 
If you dont want to use any additional stuff, you can just use the Laravel Model Events (that in fact Ardent is wrapping in the hooks). Look into the docs http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
>   points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating,
>   created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted,
>   restoring, restored.
>
> Whenever a new item is saved for the first time, the creating and
>   created events will fire. If an item is not new and the save method is
>   called, the updating / updated events will fire. In both cases, the
>   saving / saved events will fire.
>
> If false is returned from the creating, updating, saving, or deleting
>   events, the action will be cancelled:

**Solution**
Finally, reffering to you question you can utilize the above approaches in numerous ways but most obviously you can combine it (or not) with the Eloquent Models' **getDirty()** [api docs here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#2149-2167) method. It will work for example with the saving event.

```
Yourmodel::saving(function($model)
{
    foreach($model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value){
        $original= $model->getOriginal($attribute);
        echo "Changed $attribute from '$original' to '$value'<br/>\r\n";
    }
    return true; //if false the model wont save! 
});
```

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Laravel 5.3 > https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3177 .

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at the `getDirty()` method in the Eloquent model ([model.php](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#2149-2167)). 
This method should return the changed attributes.

Comment: Yes, but not on pivot relations. That, together with the inability of a Eloquent model to retrospect it's defined relations is really a miss.